# AngularJS Form ng-attr

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make a button disabled when my form is invalid:

I tried the following without any help

```
<form name="someForm" id="someForm">    
   <input type="submit" ng-attr-disabled="{{someForm.$valid}}" />
</form>
```

And

```
   <input type="submit" ng-attr-disabled="someForm.$valid" />
```

Neither of them work, am I doing something wrong?

I can get it to work using:

```
            <input type="submit" ng-show="someForm.$valid" />
            <input type="submit" ng-hide="someForm.$valid" disabled />
```

But it just seems wrong :-(

How am I supposed to use the ng-attr directive to access the form and set the disabled attribute whenever the form is not valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use [`ng-disabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive.

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="someForm.$valid" />
```

When you do `ng-attr-disabled="{{someForm.$valid}}"` what happens is it will place the attribute `disabled="true"` or `disabled="false"` which means disabled attribute is still present whether is it true/false and it will disable the button always. disabled attribute if present will disable the input it has to be completely absent to have it enabled. `ng-disabled` attribute clearly handles it. It is the property `disabled` that can be set to true/false and not the attribute disabled.

And you also would need to add ng-model and a name for any of your inputs (not for the button) inside the form, so that it is added to the formcontroller.

**Demo**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <form name="someForm" novalidate>

    <input type="text" name="mod" ng-model="mod" required />
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="someForm.$invalid" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks worked, will accept your answer once i can! So there is no way of using ng-attr-xxxx to either set or not set an attribute?

Comment: ng-attr-x is to set a value to that attribute dynamically, which is perfectly fine and which is what you are doing, but only thing is disabled attribute does not work that way.

Comment: what would be the best way to either set an attribute or unset an unttribute using angular expressions? Create a new directive for each distinct attribute? E.g. ng-required directive and ng-somecustomattr?

Comment: You would not need it. It is only for some special attributes like checked, required, disabled and they are already present